# How to add new fonts to MacTeX 2013

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, mactex

I know how to install the three adobe fonts: MinionPro, MyriadPro and MnSymbol in a Mac (OS 10.6, 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9) where MacTeX 2010 is already installed. This can be done following the steps:

1. Download texmf.cnf and texmf-extra in Desktop (these two files can be found in [MinionPro-Installation](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lyvmqudyf1ual4o/ogondYi71G/MinionPro%20-%20Mac%20Installation))
2. Enter in a terminal shell
3. Command:  sudo /bin/bash
4. Enter password
5. Command: mv /Users//Desktop/texmf-extra /usr/local
6. Command: mv /Users//Desktop/texmf.cnf   /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c
7. Command: export  PATH=/usr/texbin:$PATH
8. Command: updmap-sys  --edit
9. Add in the end of the edited file the following three lines:
   Map MinionPro.map
   Map MyriadPro.map
   Map MnSymbol.map
10. Save and wait for reconfiguration of the system - Until you get "updmap: Done"

Unfortunately these steps do not work with MacTex 2013. Apparently, step 6 has to change to:

mv /Users//Desktop/texmf.cnf   /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/web2c

but still this does not help.

Can anybody help?

Comment: That seems an odd place to move texmf-extra. What's the contents of that directory? You should not need to install MnSymbol. It is part of TeX Live by default and its map should be enabled by default. Note that I don't have a (working) Mac (or one capable of using anything like the current edition of MacTeX). In any case /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/ will not exist as that directory has been deprecated so you cannot move anything there.

Comment: The directory texmf-extra is available at the address: https://www.dropbox.com/home/public/MinionPro%20-%20Mac%20Installation/texmf-extra and contains the three fonts.

Comment: OK. I looked. I don't know why it includes MnSymbol, though, or why you would need special packages for MacTeX. Have you read https://www.tug.org/mactex/TeXLive2013Changes.pdf? It covers changes in the 2013 edition and the installation of fonts. Incidentally, I'm pretty sure redistributing those fonts (except MnSymbol) violates Adobe's licence.

Comment: That's why the packages from ctan don't include the fonts. I would use the ctan packages and follow the instructions. See http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/fonts/minionpro/README.

Comment: You might also want to look at FontPro if you have recent versions of the fonts since the CTAN package apparently doesn't work well with them.

Comment: Maybe my instructions for Minion Pro can help. It seems to be an issue with TEXMFLOCAL and TEXMFHOME. I've used them for Lucida Sans and it is the same (except for converting otf to type1 that is not needed with Lucida Sans) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251748/installing-minionpro-font-on-latex-some-problems/330350?noredirect=1#comment809434_330350