# Can't get pdflatex to work with Minion Pro on Linux

Tags: fonts, minionpro

I successfully installed Minion Pro on OS X a couple of years back using the [`FontPro`](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) tool, but I'm unable to get it to work this time around on Linux (elementary OS / Ubuntu). I installed the latest TeXLive 2016 version from the website a few weeks back, so no Ubuntu repositories were used. Everything has been working perfectly, apart from being unable to get Minion Pro to work.

Here's what I did. I downloaded `FontPro`, opened a command prompt pointing to its directory, and followed the below instructions to install the font (taken from [here](http://www.clarkdonley.com/blog/2015-03-07-installing-minionpro-for-latex-on-mac-os-x-yosemite.html) and cfr's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251814/32206)):

```
mkdir otf
cp /<my-adobe-installation-directory>/MinionPro*.otf otf
./scripts/makeall MinionPro
sudo ./scripts/install $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c
sudo echo Map MinionPro.map >> $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg
sudo mktexlsr $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)
sudo updmap-sys
```

Apart from being unable to `echo Map MinionPro.map` to the `updmap.cfg` file which I fixed by generating the file and typing the text manually, I couldn't see any errors during installation. As far as I can tell, the font was installed successfully (at least in terms of having the right files at the right places):

```
[...]/FontPro-master$ ls $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/type1/adobe/MinionPro/
MinionPro-BoldIt.pfb  MinionPro-Bold.pfb  MinionPro-It.pfb  MinionPro-Regular.pfb
[...]/FontPro-master$ cat $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg
Map MinionPro.map
```

After some general browsing around to search for a solution, I did the following:

```
[...]/FontPro-master$ kpsewhich pdftex.map
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
```

After opening the `pdftex.map` file listed above, I couldn't find any reference to Minion Pro in it. I'm assuming that's where the issue lies, but I don't know how to fix it. And in case this helps, I don't believe I ever ran `updmap`, `getnonfreefonts` or `getnonfreefonts-sys`.

This is the error I get when trying to generate a minimal document that uses `\usepackage{MinionPro}`:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MinionPro-Regular-osf-ot1): Font MinionPro-Regula
r-osf-ot1 at 545 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Finally, this is the output I get when running `sudo updmap-sys`:

```
[...]/FontPro-master$ sudo updmap-sys 
updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /home/louis) to root's actual home (/root).
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"

updmap is creating new map files
using the following configuration:
  LW35 font names                  : URWkb (default)
  prefer outlines                  : true (default)
  texhash enabled                  : true
  download standard fonts (dvips)  : true (default)
  download standard fonts (pdftex) : true (default)
  kanjiEmbed replacement string    : noEmbed (default)
  kanjiVariant replacement string  :  (default)
  create a mapfile for pxdvi       : false (default)

Scanning for LW35 support files  [  3 files]
Scanning for MixedMap entries    [  6 files]
Scanning for KanjiMap entries    [  0 files]
Scanning for Map entries         [  5 files]

Generating output for dvipdfmx...
Generating output for ps2pk...
Generating output for dvips...
Generating output for pdftex...

Files generated:
  /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
       15758 2016-10-15 19:05:12 builtin35.map
       21231 2016-10-15 19:05:12 download35.map
      159562 2016-10-15 19:05:12 psfonts_pk.map
      163413 2016-10-15 19:05:12 psfonts_t1.map
      163408 2016-10-15 19:05:12 ps2pk.map
          14 2016-10-15 19:05:12 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map
  /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
      163415 2016-10-15 19:05:12 pdftex_dl14.map
      161750 2016-10-15 19:05:12 pdftex_ndl14.map
          15 2016-10-15 19:05:12 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
  /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap:
         281 2016-10-15 19:05:12 kanjix.map

Transcript written on "/var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.log".
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
This is a test document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: FYI: CTAN already has a [`minionpro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minionpro) package, which might save you some grief. Also, there are the [`crimson`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/crimson) and [`cochineal`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cochineal) packages, which have support for the Adobe Type 1 and OTF fonts.

Comment: @jon I just had a look and those packages look great, easy to use and as classy looking as Minion Pro! So thanks! I'd still be interested in figuring out why the Minion Pro installation didn't work though, even if it's just to satisfy my curiosity. Plus, we might get to learn something about how font installations work in LaTeX. `:-)`

Comment: Oh, I think your question has merit (I was the first to upvote the question), but font installation ain't fun in my (limited) experience. And, trust me, you'd rather someone else answer your question!

Comment: if you follow the directions carefully and slowly on https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro there is no need to rely on Clark (who seems more confused now after cfr's answer)..... **kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL** or kpsexpand '$TEXMFLOCAL' should be the starting point first.

Comment: Then `sudo mkdir -p /tmp/Minion` followed by `sudo unzip scripts.zip`,,,, `cp wherever/your/otf/files/are/at /tmp/Minion/otf/` ...then after you unzip the `scripts` on `/tmp/Minion` this will create a dirextory named `pfb` which you'll need to copy along with its contents later on....create dir on `texmf`....`mkdir fonts/type1/adobe/MinionPro/`

Comment: and then `cp /tmp/Minion/pfb/*.pfb` there.....you'll most likely need **metrics-base** and **metrics-full** along with **enc-2-000** ..... go to `texmf` then unzippity unzippity pa those.....Carefully look when the metrics and enc are decompressing, for it follows a directory structure quite structured I shall say, but everything is explained at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro .... Try to get the otf fonts that you need to copy to `/tmp/Minion` from reliable sources.