# Minion Pro in Overleaf , not exactly the same as Adobe's Minion

Tags: overleaf, minionpro

I have to edit some large chunks of text, including maths, which will then be copied as images into a large document in InDesign, by a professional graphics designer I work with. It's for a book published by a learned society, and I am the editor.

The text HAS to be in the Adobe font Minion Pro Regular. Eventually, section titles should be in another font (Montserrat), but that is a later problem. I work with overleaf, and I have tried to use the package MinionPro, which I found on CTAN. I have two problems.

The first is that I don't know how to use a package like that with Overleaf. I improvise, and it sort of works, but I don't really know what I am doing. I have added:

`\usepackage{MinionPro}`

and to the Overleaf document I have added the files:

MinionPro.sty,
MinionPro-FontDef.sty,
otfontdef.sty

I have done nothing else. I get something out, which I can also scale, but for example, I can't write italics. Clearly, I don't know what I'm doing.

The bigger problem is that thing that does come out looks vaguely like Minion, but when I send a sample to my graphics designer, he says that it is not Minion. And I think he is right. When I compare them, they are indeed slightly different. Some characters, such as the question mark, is quite different.

Can some deft latex-person out there help an ignorant scientist, lacking in programming skills, with this issue? I do have the font files (from Adobe) but I have idea how to use such files with latex/overleaf.

Thanks in advance

This is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx, fancyhdr}

\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{fontsize}
\changefontsize[13.5]{10.5}

\begin{document}

Hur vet vi att \emph{Einstein} hade rätt?
        
\showoutput     
        
\end{document}
```

There are no warnings, but the (very long) log is:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.10)  22 SEP 2021 10:49
> entering extended mode
> \write18 enabled.
> %&-line parsing enabled.
> **main.tex
> (/compile/main.tex
> LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
> L3 programming layer <2020-07-17> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
> Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
> File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
> )
> \c@part=\count168
> \c@section=\count169
> \c@subsection=\count170
> \c@subsubsection=\count171
> \c@paragraph=\count172
> \c@subparagraph=\count173
> \c@figure=\count174
> \c@table=\count175
> \abovecaptionskip=\skip47
> \belowcaptionskip=\skip48
> \bibindent=\dimen134
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
> Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
> Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
> \inpenc@prehook=\toks15
> \inpenc@posthook=\toks16
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
> Package: babel 2020/07/13 3.47 The Babel package
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
> File: babel.def 2020/07/13 3.47 Babel common definitions
> \babel@savecnt=\count176
> \U@D=\dimen135
> \l@babelnohyphens=\language86
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
> \bbl@readstream=\read2
> )
> \bbl@dirlevel=\count177
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-swedish/swedish.ldf
> Language: swedish 2005/03/31 v2.3d Swedish support from the babel system
> Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 90.
> )) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
> Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
> Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
> @emptytoks=\toks17
> \symAMSa=\mathgroup4
> \symAMSb=\mathgroup5
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version` bold'
> (Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
> )) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
> Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
> Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
> \KV@toks@=\toks18
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
> Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
> Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
> File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
> )
> Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
> File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
> ))
> \Gin@req@height=\dimen136
> \Gin@req@width=\dimen137
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
> Package: fancyhdr 2019/01/31 v3.10 Extensive control of page headers and footers
> \f@nch@headwidth=\skip49
> \f@nch@O@elh=\skip50
> \f@nch@O@erh=\skip51
> \f@nch@O@olh=\skip52
> \f@nch@O@orh=\skip53
> \f@nch@O@elf=\skip54
> \f@nch@O@erf=\skip55
> \f@nch@O@olf=\skip56
> \f@nch@O@orf=\skip57
> ) (/compile/MinionPro.sty
> Package: MinionPro 2007/03/15 v2.1 MinionPro support for LaTeX
> (/compile/MinionPro-FontDef.sty
> File: MinionPro-FontDef.sty 2007/02/01 v2.2 font definition macros
> (/compile/otfontdef.sty
> Package: otfontdef 2005/06/04 v0.1e OpenType font definition
> )
> \Mn@option@normalsize=\dimen138
> Package MinionPro-FontDef Info: Configuration: smallfamily, noopticals, normalsize=12.0pt on input line 52.
> \Mn@config@cnt=\count178
> \Mn@fontdimen=\dimen139
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
> Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.sty
> Package: MnSymbol 2007/01/21 v1.4 support for the MnSymbol font
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
> Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
> @mathmargin=\skip58
> For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option. (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions \@emptytoks=\toks19 \ex@=\dimen140 )) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols \pmbraise@=\dimen141 ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names ) \inf@bad=\count179 LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227. \uproot@=\count180 \leftroot@=\count181 LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389. \classnum@=\count182 \DOTSCASE@=\count183 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489. LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610. \Mathstrutbox@=\box45 \strutbox@=\box46 \big@size=\dimen142 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734. \macc@depth=\count184 \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count185 \dotsspace@=\muskip16 \c@parentequation=\count186 \dspbrk@lvl=\count187 \tag@help=\toks20 \row@=\count188 \column@=\count189 \maxfields@=\count190 \andhelp@=\toks21 \eqnshift@=\dimen143 \alignsep@=\dimen144 \tagshift@=\dimen145 \tagwidth@=\dimen146 \totwidth@=\dimen147 \lineht@=\dimen148 \@envbody=\toks22 \multlinegap=\skip59 \multlinetaggap=\skip60 \mathdisplay@stack=\toks23 LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860. ) LaTeX Info: Redefining \dagger on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \ddagger on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \mathparagraph on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \mathsection on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \mathdollar on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \mathsterling on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \yen on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \circledR on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \circledS on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Re on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Im on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dotplus on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \thicksim on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \thickapprox on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \veebar on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \barwedge on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \doublebarwedge on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \centerdot on input line 84. LaTeX Info: Redefining \divideontimes on input line 84. \symMnSyA=\mathgroup6 \symMnSyB=\mathgroup7 \symMnSyC=\mathgroup8 \symMnSyD=\mathgroup9 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font` largesymbols' on input line 119.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version` normal'
> (Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/MnSymbolE/m/n on input line 119.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version` bold'
> (Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/MnSymbolE/m/n on input line 119.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 120. LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding` OMS' has changed to `U' for symbol font (Font)`              symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 120. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` symbols' in version `normal' (Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> U/MnSymbolF/m/n on input line 120. LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding` OMS' has changed to `U' for symbol font (Font)`              symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 120. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` symbols' in version `bold' (Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> U/MnSymbolF/m/n on input line 120. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` MnSyA' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/MnSymbolA/m/n --> U/MnSymbolA/b/n on input line 121. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` MnSyB' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/MnSymbolB/m/n --> U/MnSymbolB/b/n on input line 122. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` MnSyC' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/MnSymbolC/m/n --> U/MnSymbolC/b/n on input line 123. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` MnSyD' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/MnSymbolD/m/n --> U/MnSymbolD/b/n on input line 124. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` largesymbols' in version `bold' (Font)                  OMX/MnSymbolE/m/n --> OMX/MnSymbolE/b/n on input line 125. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` symbols' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/MnSymbolF/m/n --> U/MnSymbolF/b/n on input line 126. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathcal on input line 241. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet` \mathcal' in version `bold' (Font)                  OMS/MnSymbolS/m/n --> OMS/MnSymbolS/b/n on input line 241. LaTeX Info: Redefining \longrightarrow on input line 548. LaTeX Info: Redefining \longleftarrow on input line 549. LaTeX Info: Redefining \longleftrightarrow on input line 550. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longrightarrow on input line 551. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longleftarrow on input line 552. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longleftrightarrow on input line 553. LaTeX Info: Redefining \longmapsto on input line 554. LaTeX Info: Redefining \vdots on input line 868. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \braceld on input line 1721. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \bracelu on input line 1722. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \bracerd on input line 1723. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \braceru on input line 1724. LaTeX Info: Redefining \downbracefill on input line 1799. LaTeX Info: Redefining \upbracefill on input line 1800. LaTeX Info: Redefining \overbrace on input line 1819. LaTeX Info: Redefining \underbrace on input line 1820. LaTeX Info: Redefining \surd on input line 1843. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 1845. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 1846. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \vec on input line 1848. ) LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font` operators' on input line 163.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to` T1' for symbol font
> (Font)              `operators' in the math version` normal' on input line 163.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version` normal'
> (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n on input line 163.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to` T1' for symbol font
> (Font)              `operators' in the math version` bold' on input line 163.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version` bold'
> (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n on input line 163.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 164. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` letters' in version `normal' (Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it on input line 164. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` letters' in version `bold' (Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it on input line 164. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` operators' in version `bold' (Font)                  T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/eb/n on input line 165. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` letters' in version `bold' (Font)                  OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/eb/it on input line 166. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 167. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet` \mathbf' in version `normal' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/eb/n on input line 167. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet` \mathbf' in version `bold' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/eb/n on input line 167. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 168. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet` \mathit' in version `normal' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it on input line 168. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet` \mathit' in version `bold' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it on input line 168. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet` \mathit' in version `bold' (Font)                  T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/eb/it on input line 169. \c@mv@tabular=\count191 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` operators' in version `tabular' (Font)                  T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n --> T1/MinionPro-TOsF/m/n on input line 171. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` letters' in version `tabular' (Font)                  OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it on input line 172. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet` \mathit' in version `tabular' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it on input line 173. \c@mv@boldtabular=\count192 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` operators' in version `boldtabular' (Font)                  T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n --> T1/MinionPro-TOsF/eb/n on input line 176. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font` letters' in version `boldtabular' (Font)                  OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/eb/it on input line 177. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet` \mathit' in version `boldtabular'
> (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/MinionPro-TOsF/eb/it on input line 178.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 179.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 180.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 181.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 182.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 183.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 184.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 185.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 186.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 187.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 188.
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
> Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 35.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \sscshape on input line 39.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \ulcshape on input line 41.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 47.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \textssc on input line 48.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \textulc on input line 49.
> )
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \partial on input line 499.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \ell on input line 501.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Setting MinionPro-LF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 521.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Setting MinionPro-TLF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 522.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Setting MinionPro-OsF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 523.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Setting MinionPro-TOsF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 524.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \LaTeX on input line 596.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+MinionPro-OsF on input line 628.
> LaTeX Font Info:    No file T1MinionPro-OsF.fd. on input line 628.

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n' undefined (Font)              using` T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 628.

> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontsize/fontsize.sty
> Package: fontsize 2020/05/24 v0.2 'fontsize' package. Set main font sizes (Ivan Valbusa)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
> Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
> \XKV@toks=\toks24
> \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks25
> )
> \XKV@depth=\count193
> File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
> )) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
> Package: etoolbox 2020/07/15 v2.5i e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
> \etb@tempcnta=\count194
> ))

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n' in size <10.5> not available
> (Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 9.

> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
> File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-29 L3 backend support: PDF mode
> \l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count195
> \l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
> ) (/compile/output.aux)
> \openout1 = `output.aux'.

> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
> \scratchcounter=\count196
> \scratchdimen=\dimen149
> \scratchbox=\box48
> \nofMPsegments=\count197
> \nofMParguments=\count198
> \everyMPshowfont=\toks26
> \MPscratchCnt=\count199
> \MPscratchDim=\dimen150
> \MPnumerator=\count266
> \makeMPintoPDFobject=\count267
> \everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks27
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
> Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
> Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
> File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
> ))

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it' undefined (Font)              using` T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n' instead on input line 13.

> Completed box being shipped out [1]
> \vbox(680.0+0.0)x421.0
> .\glue 20.0
> .\vbox(660.0+0.0)x390.0, shifted 31.0
> ..\vbox(13.0+0.0)x390.0, glue set 13.0fil
> ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
> ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x390.0
> ..\glue 25.0
> ..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
> ..\vbox(592.0+0.0)x390.0, glue set 579.93805fil
> ...\write-{}
> ...\write1{\babel@aux{swedish}{}}
> ...\glue(\topskip) 4.45851
> ...\hbox(7.54149+0.0)x390.0, glue set 214.47093fil
> ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x13.5
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 H
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 u
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 r
> ....\glue 3.63054 plus 1.81337 minus 1.20892
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 v
> ....\kern-0.30225
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 e
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 t
> ....\glue 3.63054 plus 1.81337 minus 1.20892
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 v
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 i
> ....\glue 3.63054 plus 1.81337 minus 1.20892
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 a
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 t
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 t
> ....\kern 0.0
> ....\glue 3.63054 plus 1.81337 minus 1.20892
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 E
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 i
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 n
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 s
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 t
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 e
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 i
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 n
> ....\kern 0.0
> ....\glue 3.63054 plus 1.81337 minus 1.20892
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 h
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 a
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 d
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 e
> ....\glue 3.63054 plus 1.81337 minus 1.20892
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 r
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 �
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 t
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 t
> ....\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 ?
> ....\penalty 10000
> ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
> ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
> ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
> ...\glue 0.0
> ...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
> ..\glue(\baselineskip) 22.91861
> ..\hbox(7.08139+0.0)x390.0, glue set 192.27803fil
> ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
> ...\T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n/10.95 1
> ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil

> {/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} (/compile/output.aux)

> LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
> (Font)              up to 0.45pt have occurred.

> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

> )
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
> 6765 strings out of 480906
> 88462 string characters out of 5908280
> 320927 words of memory out of 5000000
> 22314 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
> 537682 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
> 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
> 50i,4n,45p,857b,126s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
> {/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1095.pfb>
> Output written on /compile/output.pdf (1 page, 16282 bytes).
> PDF statistics:
> 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
> 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
> 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
> 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the staff of overleaf?

Comment: I have not, but it's good idea. I will do that. If they solve my problem, I will post the answer as an answer to my own question.

Comment: also if you want help here you should probably edit the question to include a small 1-paragraph document including italic and a ? and add `\showoutput` and show the full log you get from overleaf. Impossible for anyone to debug "Some characters, such as the question mark, is quite different." given no information about the input, the output or any warnings given by tex.

Comment: Thank you, but the conclusion may in that case that I have to start with taking a course in how to use this site. I have no tex-warnings. If I manage to figure out the correct way to ask the question, I will edit it accordingly. If am not able to do that, I will leave the patricians here alone. Thanks.

Comment: No idea how to solve your problem, but first the documentation says `amssymb` is not compatible, so I guess you should remove this package. Also, you need to install the fonts as explained in the README here (it is nicely explained and is too large for a comment) https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro, using the scripts provided in the .zip file. To adapt the installaton to Overleaf... I guess you need to convert locally the files,and then use this method to load it https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F

Comment: As @tobiasBora said, you need to install the fonts on overleaf. If you use Lua- or XeLaTeX and fontspec you could spare yourself the trouble converting opentype fonts to postscript.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all! Overleaf technicians answered as pasted below. Thanks to that and your help above, I think I will be able to solve the problem.

Thanks for getting in touch!

The MinionPro package on CTAN is pretty old (2007) and provides facilities for using Minion in Adobe Type 1 format. The Type 1 format is being deprecated in favour of Open Type. The MinionPro package provides scripts for converting OpenType fonts to Type 1, but that would some work on your part, and may not be the best route to take.

If you have purchased Minion, our recommendation is to avoid using the MinionPro package (aimed at Type 1 fonts), and use XeTeX or LuaLaTeX with the commercial MinionPro OpenType fonts. You can upload the .otf or .ttf font files to your Overleaf project, then follow the steps 1, 2, 4 on this help page.

I hope that helps a bit! If you are then still having problems getting XeLaTeX + fontspec + MinionPro truetype/opentype font files to work in your Overleaf project, please send us your Overleaf project's URL, and we'll have a look. There's no need to turn on link-sharing, you can just copy the URL from the browser address bar.

Comment: This answer basically confirms the answer given by DG'. I guess you can accept his answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, oneside, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{fontsize}
\changefontsize[13.5]{10.5}

\begin{document}

Hur vet vi att \emph{Einstein} hade rätt?
        
\showoutput     
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

This will embed the right fonts:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
LHQCSY+MinionPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
LPFZUZ+MinionPro-It                  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
```

Comment: For this to work in overleaf with lualatex, you just need to upload the otf font at the root?

Comment: Also, it I'm not wrong you're not using `\usepackage{MinionPro}` anymore. Any idea if this package can still be used (for example I see that it provides many options), or is lualatex supposed to be as powerful as this package?

Comment: @tobiasBora – You are right, you have to upload the font to overleaf to make it work (not necessarily in the root directory, you can specify a path). And indeed, `fontspec` replaces the old `MinionPro` package and should let you use all the opentype features of the font. The [manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/fontspec.pdf/0) can help you figure out how.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you write mathematics, then the old MinionPro package is superior.